# Cannot attach DirectX Pix to firefox

Tags: debugging, directx, directx-11

I tried to attach PIX to Mozilla Firefox. But the problem is that it displays an error saying "The title exited before performing any GPU work". The error code is E_PIX_CAPTURE_NO_GPU_WORK (0x8ABC01F8).

[image: Error]

Is it because when I launch, until it is necessary a device is not created? How do I take care of that? I have to launch it instead of attaching since I want to perform a GPU capture.

I'm using the 1810.02 release of PIX and firefox 63.03.

Interestingly when I try to launch chrome, there is no error, but when I try to perform a capture it throws an error. The error code is E_FAIL (0x80004005).

```
                                  --UPDATE--
```

So I got it to work using RenderDoc. I had to launch and attach to all the child processes. But unfortunately WebGL stopped working which was what I was trying to debug.

Comment: Are you sure Firefox is actually using DirectX 12?

Comment: I think firefox uses Directx 11. Doesn't PIX support directx 11?

Comment: The modern version of [PIX on Windows](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pix/2017/01/17/introducing-pix-on-windows-beta/) only supports DirectX 12. If you happen to be running Windows 10 October 2018 Update you can force it to use the [11on12](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pix/2018/10/04/pix-1810-02-direct3d11-and-winml/) layer which makes a DirectX 11 application use DirectX 12, but that's probably not quite what you wanted here. The Visual Studio Graphics Diagnostics (a.k.a. VSPIX) tool was the last one to support 'native' DirectX 11.

Answer (score 0):

**Firefox is a Direct3D 11 application, but the modern [PIX on Windows](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pix/2017/01/17/introducing-pix-on-windows-beta/) tool only supports DirectX 12 applications.**

> With the Windows 10 October 2018 Update, you can force the use of the "11 on 12" translation later which will show up as DirectX 12 in PIX on Windows, but that doesn't really tell you much about the original application's use of Direct3D 11. See [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pix/2018/10/04/pix-1810-02-direct3d11-and-winml/).

[Visual Studio Graphics Diagnostics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/graphics/visual-studio-graphics-diagnostics?view=vs-2017) (a.k.a. VSPIX) is the last version to have native Direct3D 11 support.